# jquery Auto complete response coming as array how can i call two fields like name and photo

Tags: php, html, arrays, ajax

[image]This is the form field with input type text.

```
<span>
<img  src="images/author2.jpg" width="50" />  //in Database i have profilepic/userimage.jpg and the image shown in above is a static image.
<input class="searchStudent" type="text" autocomplete="off">
</span>
```

I have entered letter "A" and the response is coming as a array.i want to show the photo and names of the user how can i do that...?

This is my from script to get the details:

```
/*Search Student starts here*/
$(document).on("focus keyup", "input.searchStudent", function (event) {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: 'gdcontroller.php?action=search',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.value = ui.item.label;
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.value = ui.item.label;
        }

    });
});
/*Search Student ends here*/
```

This is my controller, here I am searching available students with name "A"
and fetching their details:

```
if($_GET['action']=="search" && $_GET['term']!='')
{
    $keysearch = $_GET['term'];
    $studentValue = trim($_GET['studentname']);

    $studentsQuery =$conn->query('select s.student_pid,i.email,s.student_email,s.student_fname,s.student_lname,s.profile_pic from r_job_invitations i 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_students s ON i.email = s.student_email where i.id_job =54 and accounttype = 1 and inv_res = 1 and student_fname LIKE "'.$keysearch.'%" OR student_lname LIKE "'.$keysearch.'%" ')or die(mysqli_error());

    $studentData = array();
    while($student = $studentsQuery->fetch_assoc()){
        $studentData[]= $student;
    }
    echo json_encode($studentData);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="photoContainer"></div>

$(document).on("focus keyup", "input.searchStudent", function(event) {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: 'gdcontroller.php?action=search',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //I'm having trouble here; even name is not coming:
            student.student_fname.value = ui.item.student.student_fname;
            $("#photoContainer").append('<img src="' + ui.item.student.profile_pic + '">'); 
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.value = ui.item.label;
        }    
    });
});
```

Comment: even i am not getting first name but when fetch only name in controller i am able to get only name. by replacing this  `this.value = ui.item.label;` above to your `$("#photoContainer").append`

Comment: When Enter 1 Character , its showing Blank, Labels are Missing in Auto Completed. How can i Set the label for Autocomplete. But Values are coming.